# objects with child of contraints "exploded" when I reopened my file

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, parent

I have modeled several robotic arms. Each segment on an arm is an object with a "child of" constraint targeting the adjacent segment closer to the base of the arm. Everything was working and I saved, but now when I reopen the file all the segments are massively spaced apart from one another and shooting off into the distance. It's like this on my older saves too. What's going on?

Here's what it looks like, these floating bits used to be connected. 
[image: _]
[image: _]
[image: _]

Comment: Provide at least a screenshot.

Comment: ta-da, I don't do alot of rigging so I don't know what to make of this

Comment: Start by checking the blender console window for errors, my guess is dependency loops.

Comment: Posted console screenshot in question. This is all I get, looks standard I think. I haven't used the console in blender before so not sure what the procedure for error checking is. Is there a specific command I should run?